# What statistical method would be best to use for description and forecasting?

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis

I have come across this question and don't know what statistical method should be used.

A business has 1000 customers who regularly spend between £100 per annum to £2000 per annum. The business creates a e-commerce "webshop" and 20 customers start to use this form of buying the product. We can assume that we have all the customer data.

How can we determine if there is any revenue uplift as a result of ordering on-line, and how would you dimension what that increase is?

Comment: if this is HW please add the self-study tag

Comment: No this is not HW, its a practice interview question

Comment: The [self-study tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) is still relevant. Have a look at the link. You need to show what you tried in order to solve your issue: `Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If don't seem to be making a genuine attempt, your question might be voted down or closed.`

Comment: You may give illustrative data fortwo or three years especially revenue to enable a better answer.